# Multiple Views on one Container View

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I currently have some coding in place that I followed from a tutorial to allow multiple view controllers inside one container view and the use of custom segues with identifiers to present a new view controller when a row in a table is selected.

I am coding in xamarin.ios

Now I have the row selected part working and it activates the correct line in my ContainerViewController. However, it then throws an error when the PerformSegue is activated as it says that

> Objective-C exception thrown. name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Reciever () has no segue with identifier 'test1'

I have the segue with the id test1 so the id is correct but stills throws that error.

This is the tutorial I followed: https://kodesnippets.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/container-view-in-ios/

This is the code for ContainerViewController:

```
namespace PMApp
{
    public partial class ContainerViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ContainerViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }
        public ContainerViewController() : base("ContainerViewController", null){}

        UIViewController vc;
        string segueIdentifier;
        UIViewController lastViewController;

        public void segueIdentifireRecievedFromParent(int selectedRow)
        {
            ContainerViewController containerController = new ContainerViewController();

            if (selectedRow == 0)
            {
                segueIdentifier = "test1";
                PerformSegue(segueIdentifier, null);

            }
            else if (selectedRow == 1)
            {
                segueIdentifier = "test2";
                PerformSegue(segueIdentifier, null);
            }
        }

        public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
        {
            base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

            if (segue.Identifier == segueIdentifier)
            {
                if (lastViewController != null)
                {
                    lastViewController.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
                }

                vc = segue.DestinationViewController as UIViewController;
                AddChildViewController(vc);
                View.AddSubview(vc.View);
                vc.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
                lastViewController = vc;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

This is the class which handles my table and row selection:

```
namespace PMApp.Classes
{
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        List<string> TableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "AreaCell";

        public TableSource(List<string> items)
        {
            TableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return TableItems.Count;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
            string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
            { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            ContainerViewController containerController = new ContainerViewController();

            containerController.segueIdentifireRecievedFromParent(indexPath.Row);
            //MainViewController.PresentContainerView(indexPath.Row);  
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }

        private void newAlertView()
        {
            var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Title", "Message", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("back", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully somebody can help, been searching everywhere on the solution but just cant find nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: Because you are simply creating a new instance of `ContainerViewController` by calling its initialiser, that instance is not associated with the storyboard and therefore knows nothing about segues.  You need to retrieve the view controller instance by calling `instantiateViewController` on the `UIStoryboard` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @Paulw11 said we should not create a new instance of the `ContainerViewController` in the `RowSelected()` event. This instance is not what you put in the Storyborad, so it can't be aware of all the configuration in the Storyboard you have done.

Let's assume you put the ContainerView in the ViewController which the TableView lies. We could get the instance from Storyboard through:

```
ContainerViewController containerViewController;
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    if (segue.Identifier == "Container")
    {
        containerViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as ContainerViewController;
    }
}
```

Then pass this `containerViewController` to `TableSource`. At last you can call the `ContainerViewController`'s method in the `RowSelected()` event:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    container.segueIdentifireRecievedFromParent(indexPath.Row);
}
```

But I want to recommend you to use another way to "change" the `containerViewController`'s container. From your link the author just use segue to add controllers and their views to the containerView. There's no need to use segue, we can add them directly:

**Firstly, create two constrollers in the storyboard and set their Storyboard ID in the controller's property tab.**

**Then we can use them in the `ContainerViewController`:**

```
UIViewController lastViewController;
private void addSubsFrom(string viewControllersIdentifier)
{
    if (lastViewController != null)
    {
        lastViewController.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
        lastViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
    }

    var viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(viewControllersIdentifier);
    viewController.View.Frame = View.Bounds;

    View.AddSubview(viewController.View);
    AddChildViewController(viewController);

    lastViewController = viewController;
}

public void segueIdentifireRecievedFromParent(int selectedRow)
{
    if (selectedRow == 0)
    {
        addSubsFrom("TestAVC");

    }
    else if (selectedRow == 1)
    {
        addSubsFrom("TestBVC");
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/landl0526/ContainerViewDemo.git) is my sample for you referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used your solution and it worked great. However, to get it to work, I could not use a list for the table cell titles because it would throw a null exception. So because this is the case, how would i go about changing the title of each cell but still keep the functionality please?

Comment: How do you pass the lists? In the 'TableSource''s construct method, can you get the correct lists?

Comment: I use the TableSource constructor where you have container = viewcontroller. This is where I passed the list in using TableSource(List<string> items)

Comment: I just post an example. you can customize it yourself. If you want the list, your constructor may be like: TableSource(List<string> items, ContainerViewController viewController).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That worked great. Im a bit new to programming so just getting my head around things still but thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helps you.